# comment box using PHP and HTML is returning only last comment information for report form

Tags: php, html, mysql, comments

I have created a user comment section for my website and comments are displaying on the web page along with the flag to report abuse. it has five columns in database comment_id, username, email, comment and post_id on which user is commenting.  following is the php code that i use to display the comments from the database:

```
try
 {
  $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_comment WHERE post_id ='$post_id'");
 $result->execute();
 $count=$result->rowCount();

 $def_com = $count;
 if(!$count)
    {
      $def_com = "Be the First one to comment.";
    }
else{
    $data = array();
    while ($data = $result->fetch())
    {
        $datas[] = $data;
    }
    foreach ($datas as $data)
    {
    echo " <div class='col-md-12 com-row' >
    <img src='img/user.png' style='height:60px;width:60px;align:left'>"
    ." <p style='margin-left:80px; margin-top:-50px'> b>".$data['user_name']."</b>&nbsp;". 
                             $data['time']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$data['comment_id']."<br>".$data['comment']. "</p>
    <a class='flagBtn smGlobalBtn flagdiv' name='report-comment' href='reportabuse.php'></a><br><br>";
}
```

it is working fine displaying all the comments on a given post. i have got the post id in session variable and use it in select statement.

MY issue is when i click on flag button i want the comment id to be passed on to the reportabuse.php page. this id should be corresponding to the comment where use has clicked the flag button.

how to get it i have tried session variable but it is passing the id of last comment does not matter on which comment flag user clicks.

whatever comment information i try to past from the post page to report abuse page it is displaying information of the last comment only does not matter which comment's flag button is being clicked. I need information of only that comment whose flag button is being clicked.

i tried using form also  to display the comments but no use the problem was still there.

Comment: is it okay to pass id in url like this href='reportabuse.php?comments_id=2

Comment: thanx for the response.it worked....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not pass the id as a parameter in the URL of the a href for example href='reportabuse.php?cid=1234'
On the reportabuse.php page interogate the $_GET["cid"] for the id passed in the url.

More about $_GET http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: when i submit the report abuse form its giving an error: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: cid in "Filepath" on line 5 how to remove this.

Comment: i tried if(isset($_GET['cid'])){
 $comment_id = $_GET['cid'];} as well as if(isset($_POST['cid'])){
 $comment_id = $_GET['cid'];} but then its not returning any thing at all.

Comment: Are you doing a post to the page with the params in the URL or part of the form ?

Comment: There is also an error with the second option - you are checking $_POST variable and then if it is valid you are calling the $_GET variable. This will definitely cause a problem if it passes the validation .